# SSE interleave/merge/combine 2 vectors using a mask, per-element conditional move?

Tags: c, x86, simd, sse

Essentially i am trying to implement a ternary-like operation on 2 SSE (`__m128`) vectors.
The mask is another `__m128` vector obtained from `_mm_cmplt_ps`.

What i want to achieve is to select element of vector `a` when the corresponding element of the mask is `0xffff'ffff` and element of `b` when the mask's element is `0`.

Example of the desired operation (in semi-pseudocode):

```
const __m128i mask = {0xffffffff, 0, 0xffffffff, 0};  // e.g. a compare result
const __m128 a = {1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3};
const __m128 b = {2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3};
const __m128 c = interleave(a, b, mask); // c contains {1.0, 2.1, 1.2, 2.3}
```

I am having trouble implementing this operation in SIMD (SSE) intrinsics.
My original idea was to mix `a` and `b` using moves and then shuffle the elements using the mask, however `_mm_shuffle_ps` takes an `int` mask consisting of 4-bit indices, not an `__m128` mask.

Another idea was to use something akin to a conditional move, but there does not seem to be a conditional move in SSE (or at least I did not manage to find it in Intel's guide).

How is this normally done in SSE?

Comment: That's called a "blend", you're looking for `blendvps`, or without SSE4.1 emulate it with ANDN/AND/OR.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you! Could you also please explain the emulation process without SSE4.1?

Comment: (a & mask) | (b & ~mask)

Comment: Or `a ^ ((b ^ a) & m` which saves one operation for constant `a ^ b`.

Comment: Related (probably a duplicate ?) : https://stackoverflow.com/q/8004718/253056

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That's called a "blend"**.
Intel's intrinsics guide groups blend instructions [under the "swizzle" category](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,Other&ig_expand=6936,5239,5263,518&text=blend&cats=Swizzle), along with shuffles.

You're looking for SSE4.1 [`blendvps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/blendvps) (intrinsic `_mm_blendv_ps`).  The other element sizes are `_mm_blendv_pd` and `_mm_blendv_epi8`.  These use the high bit of the corresponding element as the control, so you can use a float directly (without `_mm_cmp_ps`) if its sign bit is interesting.

```
__m128i mask = _mm_castps_si128(_mm_cmplt_ps(x, y));   // integer 0 / -1 bit patterns
__m128 c = _mm_blendv_ps(b, a, mask);  // copy element from 2nd op where the mask is set
```

Note that I reversed `a, b` to `b, a` because SSE blends take the element from the 2nd operand in positions where the mask was set.  Like a conditional-move which copies when the condition is true.  If you name your constants / variables accordingly, you can write `blend(a,b, mask)` instead of having them backwards.  Or give them meaningful names line `ones` and `twos`.

---

In other cases **where your control operand is a constant**, there's also **`_mm_blend_ps`** / pd / `_mm_blend_epi16` (an 8-bit immediate operand can only control 8 separate elements, so 8x 2-byte.)

##### Performance

`blendps xmm, xmm, imm8` is a single-uop instruction for any vector ALU port on Intel CPUs, as cheap as `andps`.  (https://uops.info/).  `pblendw` is also single-uop, but only runs on port 5 on Intel, competing with shuffles.  AVX2 `vpblendd` blends with dword granularity, an integer version of `vblendps`, and with the same very good efficiency.  (It's an integer-SIMD instruction; unlike shuffles, blends have extra bypass latency on Intel CPUs if you mix integer and FP SIMD.)

But variable `blendvps` is 2 uops on Intel before Skylake (and only for port 5).  And the AVX version (`vblendvps`) is unfortunately still 2 uops on Intel (3 on Alder Lake-P, 4 on Alder Lake-E).  Although the uops can at least run on any of 3 vector ALU ports.

The `vblendvps` version is funky in asm because it has 4 operands, not overwriting any of the inputs registers.  (The non-AVX version overwrites one input, and uses XMM0 implicitly as the mask input.)  Intel uops apparently can't handle 4 separate registers, only 3 for stuff like FMA, `adc`, and `cmov`.  (**And AVX-512 `vpternlogd` which can do a bitwise blend as a single uop**)

AMD has fully efficient handling of `vblendvps`, single uop (except for YMM on Zen1) with 2/clock throughput.

---

#### Without SSE4.1, you can emulate with ANDN/AND/OR

`(x&~mask) | (y&mask)` is equivalent to `_mm_blendv_ps(x,y,mask)`, except it's pure bitwise so all the bits of each mask element should match the top bit.  (e.g. a compare result, or broadcast the top bit with `_mm_srai_epi32(mask, 31)`.)

Compilers know this trick and will use it when auto-vectorizing scalar code if you compile without any arch options like `-march=haswell` or whatever.  (SSE4.1 was new in 2nd-gen Core 2, so it's increasingly widespread but not universal.)

#### For constant / loop-invariant `a^b` without SSE4.1

`x ^ ((x ^ y) & mask` saves one operation if you can reuse `x ^ y`.  (Suggested in comments by Aki).  Otherwise this is worse, longer critical-path latency and no instruction-level parallelism.

Without AVX non-destructive 3-operand instructions, this way would need a `movaps xmm,xmm` register-copy to save `b`, but it can choose to destroy the `mask` instead of `a`.  The AND/ANDN/OR way would normally destroy its 2nd operand, the one you use with `y&mask`, and destroy the mask with ANDN (`~mask & x`).

With AVX, `vblendvps` is guaranteed available.  Although if you're targeting Intel (especially Haswell) and don't care about AMD, you might still choose an AND/XOR if `a^b` can be pre-computed.

## Blending with `0`: just `AND[N]`

(Applies to integer and FP; the bit-pattern for `0.0f` and `0.0` is all-zeros, same as integer `0`.)

You don't need to copy a zero from anywhere, just `x & mask`, or `x & ~mask`.

(The `(x & ~mask) | (y & mask)` expression reduces to this for x=0 or y=0; that term becomes zero, and `z|=0` is a no-op.)

For example, to implement `x = mask ? x+y : x`, which would put the latency of an add and blend on the critical path, you simplify to `x += select y or zero according to mask`, i.e. to `x += y & mask;`  Or to do the opposite, `x += ~mask & y` using `_mm_andn_ps(mask, vy)`.

This has an ADD and an AND operation (so already cheaper than blend on some CPUs, and you don't need a 0.0 source operand in another register).  Also, the dependency chain through `x` now only includes the `+=` operation, if you were doing this in a loop with loop-carried `x` but independent `y & mask`.  e.g. summing only matching elements of an array, `sum += A[i]>=thresh ? A[i] : 0.0f;`

For an example of an extra slowdown due to lengthening the critical path unnecessarily, see [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875325/gcc-optimization-flag-o3-makes-code-slower-than-o2) where GCC's scalar asm using `cmov` has that flaw, doing `cmov` as part of the loop-carried dependency chain instead of to prepare a `0` or `arr[i]` input for it.

## Clamping to a MIN or MAX

If you want something like `a < upper ? a : upper`, you can do that clamping in one instruction with `_mm_min_ps` instead of `cmpps` / `blendvps`.  (Similarly `_mm_max_ps`, and `_mm_min_pd` / `_mm_max_pd`.)

See [What is the instruction that gives branchless FP min and max on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196817/what-is-the-instruction-that-gives-branchless-fp-min-and-max-on-x86) for details on their exact semantics, including a longstanding (but recently fixed) GCC bug where the FP intrinsics didn't provide the expected strict-FP semantics of which operand would be the one to keep if one was NaN.

Or for integer, SSE2 is highly non-orthogonal (signed min/max for int16_t, unsigned min/max for uint8_t).  Similar for saturating pack instructions.  SSE4.1 fills in the missing operand-size and signedness combinations.

- Signed: SSE2 `_mm_max_epi16` (and corresponding `min`s for all of these)

  - SSE4.1 `_mm_max_epi32` / `_mm_max_epi8`; AVX-512 `_mm_max_epi64`
- Unsigned: SSE2 `_mm_max_epu8`

  - SSE4.1 `_mm_max_epu16` / `_mm_max_epu32`; AVX-512 `_mm_max_epu64`

## AVX-512 makes masking/blending a first-class operation

AVX-512 compares into a mask register, `k0..k7` (intrinsic types `__mmask16` and so on).  Merge-masking or zero-masking can be part of most ALU instructions.  There is also a dedicated blend instruction that blends according to a mask.

I won't go into the details here, suffice it to say if you have a lot of conditional stuff to do, AVX-512 is great (even if you only use 256-bit vectors to avoid the turbo clock speed penalties and so on.)  And you'll want to read up on the details for AVX-512 specifically.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Peter Cordes in the comments to the question, the `blendvps` instruction (`_mm_blendv_*` intrinsics) is used to preform the interleave/conditional move operation.

It should be noted that `_mm_blendv_*` family select the left-hand elements if the mask contains `0` instead of `0xffffffff`, thus `a` and `b` should be passed in reverse order.

The implementation then would look like this

```
const __m128i mask = {0xffffffff, 0, 0xffffffff, 0};  // e.g. a compare result
const __m128 m_ps = _mm_castsi128_ps(mask);
const __m128 a = {1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3};
const __m128 b = {2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3};

#ifdef __SSE4_1__ // _mm_blendv_ps requires SSE4.1 
const __m128 c = _mm_blendv_ps(b, a, m_ps);
#else
const __m128 c = _mm_or_ps(_mm_and_ps(m_ps, a), _mm_andnot_ps(m_ps, b));
#endif
// c contains {1.0, 2.1, 1.2, 2.3}
```